# How do I use a private php class member variable as a key in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to access a private member variable to use as a key in an array.

My class looks similar to this:

```html
<?php
class MyClassName {
  private $value;
  private function MyFunction($array){
    $some_html = "<b> $array[$this->value] <b>"; // error occurring on this line
    return some_html;
  }
}
?>
```

The error that I am getting is

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting ']`

If I store the private member variable before using it in the array there is no syntax error. This is interpreted fine:

```html
<?php
class MyClassName {
  private $value;
  private function MyFunction($array){
    $cache_key = $this->value;
    $some_html = "<b> $array[$cache_key] <b>";
    return $some_html;
  }
}
?>
```

Is there something I am missing? I want to improve my understanding of what is happening here. Thanks.

Comment: And what does `MyFunction` returns, actually, when you run it (in second case)?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your first example, and in the second you are copying the `$value` to `$cache_key` but not using it. My guess is that there is a syntax error somewhere in your real code.

Comment: Works here: https://3v4l.org/MgG62

Comment: Sorry about that I updated the examples to more closely show what is going on.  I am trying to return a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$some_html = "<b> ".$array[$this->value]." </b>";
```

Comment: Thank you @DNT that fixed my problem!